# convert output of UDF

Tags: arrays, casting, pyspark

On Pyspark, I defined an UDF as follow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def closest_point(point, points):
    """ Find closest point from a list of points. """
    return points[cdist([point], points).argmin()]

udf_closest_point = udf(closest_point)

dfC1 = dfC1.withColumn("closest", udf_closest_point(dfC1.point, dfC1.points))
```

And my data looks like this:

- point = [0.2,0.5] or [0.1,0.6] - array of float
- points =  [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,0]] - array of array of float
- closest = for example, '[0, 1]' - a string (which is one of the value
  from point converted as string)

What should I change for my UDF to bring back an array of float instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the return type of UDF as array of floats `ArrayType(FloatType())`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, FloatType
udf_closest_point = udf(closest_point, ArrayType(FloatType()))
```